# ideals of ring of Gaussian integers modulo $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, gaussian-integers

In the ring of integers modulo $n$, $\mathbb{Z}_n$, we have all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are principal and they are $\langle d\rangle$, where $d$ is a divisor of $n$ and prime ideals are $\langle p\rangle$ where $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$.

What about the ring of Gaussian integers modulo $n$, $\mathbb{Z}_n[i]$, In this ring, whether all the ideals are principal and which are the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_n[i]$ and which of them are principal?

Since these rings are not integral domains in general, I cannot use results about PID or UFD.

Comment: The ring of Gaussian integers is a PID. Thus all $\Bbb Z_n[i]Î$ have only principal ideals.

Comment: PID is classification only for integral domains, it's not applicable here.

Comment: I suggest you to look [at this article of Wikipedia about Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Principal_ideals). Recall that $$\Bbb Z_n [i] \cong \Bbb Z[i] / (n)$$ thus ideals are principal.

Comment: You have a surjective homomorphism of rings $f:\Bbb{Z}[i]\to\Bbb{Z}_n[i]$. If $I$ is an ideal of the latter ring, then $f^{-1}(I)$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Therefore $f^{-1}(I)$ is principal with some generator $z$. It follows (surjectivity) that $I$ is generated by $f(z)$.

Comment: In fact, Jyrki's lovely argument shows that any quotient of a principal ideal ring is likewise a principal ideal ring.

Comment: So, I got all the ideals are principal. Now, any rule or formula to list all the distinct ideals, as in thecase of Z_n. Not found in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ring $\mathbb{Z}_n[i]$ can be seen as the quotient $$\Bbb Z_n [i] \cong \Bbb Z[i] / (n).$$ One of the isomorphism theorems, which can be found on every algebra book, says that the ideals of a quotient $R/A$ are in bijection with the ideals of $R$ that contain $A$, and the bijection is given by $$B \mapsto B/A = \{b+A : b \in B\}.$$Because $\Bbb Z[i]$ is a PID, every ideal that contains $(n)$ is of the form $(m)$, where $m \mid n$. If $$n=p_1^{k_1} \ldots p_r^{k_r}$$is the decomposition of $n$ as product of primes (in $\Bbb Z [i]$), then any ideal containing $(n)$ is of the form $(p_1^{s_1} \ldots p_r^{s_r})$, where $s_j \leq k_j$ and, in particular, there are $(k_1+1) \ldots (k_r+1)$ different ideals, which, in turn, correspond to different ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_n[i]$.\
Note that there is nothing particular of $\Bbb Z [i]$ apart from being a PID that we are using here. The same method proves how to find all the ideals in the quotient of a PID by one of its ideals, as you would do with $\Bbb Z _n$, but now taking into account that you need to factorise in $\Bbb Z[i]$ so, for example, $5$ is not prime because $5=(2+i)(2-i)$.

As it has been said in the comments, every ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_n[i]$ is principal. This is a general result. If you look back to the correspondence of ideals in a quotient, if $B$ is generated by $b$, then $B/A$ is generated by $b+A$.

Comment: Sir, I wish to get some clarifications  1) Will there be $(k_1+1)(k_2+1) \cdots (k_r+1)$ different ideals for $Z_n[i]$.    2) Can I get an illustration of all ideals of $Z_{12}[i]$ as an example    3 )Any references for the informations provided. 4) In $\mathbb{Z}_{12}[i], $ will the ideal $<1+11i>$ be corresponding to the ideal $<1-i> $ containing $<12>$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @sabeelmsk 1. Yes 2. In $\Bbb Z [i]$, you can write $12=3(1+i)^2(1-i)^2$ and therefore there are 18 ideals: $<1+i>$, $<1-i>$, $<3>$, $<3(1+i)>$, $<(1+i)^2>$ etc. 3. As I told you, any algebra book For example, M. Artin's "Algebra", chapters 10 and 11. 4. The ideal $<1+11i>$ corresponds to the ideal $<1+11i, 12>$. Recall that in a PID, $<a,b>$ is the ideal generated by their greatest common divisor, so one has to find $\gcd (1+11i,12)$. The general method involves the euclidean algorithm for $\Bbb Z [i]$, but in this case, as you already have a candidate, it is easier (+)

Comment: (+) Because you have a norm $N(a+bi) = a^2+b^2$ which is multiplicative, and therefore $N(\gcd(z,w))$ divides $\gcd (N(z), N(w))$. In our case, $\gcd (N(12), N(1+11i)) = \gcd(144,122)=2$, you can check by hand that $1-i$ divides both $12$ and $1+11i$ and therefore $\gcd(1+11i,12)=z(1-i)$. Taking norms on both sides, $N(z)=1$ so $z$ is a unit and $\gcd(1+11i,12)=(1-i)$ as desired